# Find all or collection groovy JSON parser

Tags: groovy

I have question how to make "findAll" or "collection" with condition.

Check the sample of XML:

```
<INVOIC02>
   <IDOC>
      <E1EDP01>
         <POSEX>000010</POSEX>
         <MENGE>0</MENGE>
         <GEWEI>GRM</GEWEI>
         <PSTYV>ZTAN</PSTYV>
         <WERKS>1528</WERKS>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000010120368</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Rocephin Vial 1g</KTEXT>
         </E1EDP19>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>003</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>07640149612004</IDTNR>
         </E1EDP19>
      </E1EDP01>
      <E1EDP01>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>010</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>OBD-2</IDTNR>
         </E1EDP19>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000010120368</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Rocephin Vial 1g</KTEXT>
         </E1EDP19>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>003</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>07640149612004</IDTNR>
         </E1EDP19>
      </E1EDP01>
   </IDOC>
</INVOIC02>
```

When structure "E1EDP19" the "QUALF" equals 002 - build in the values of 'itemCode' from "E1EDP19->IDTNR" and 'itemName'"E1EDP19->KTEXT", when "QUALF" 010 build - 'batchNo' from "E1EDP19->IDTNR".

Code below:

```
 import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder 
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import javax.xml.ws.Response
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

class ParsingXML {
    static main (args) {
     /*
        Parsing the XML as text using XmlSlurper class
        */    
        def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVOIC02>
   <IDOC>
      <E1EDP01>
         <POSEX>000010</POSEX>
         <MENGE>0</MENGE>
         <GEWEI>GRM</GEWEI>
         <PSTYV>ZTAN</PSTYV>
         <WERKS>1528</WERKS>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000010120368</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Rocephin Vial 1g</KTEXT>
         </E1EDP19>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>003</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>07640149612004</IDTNR>
         </E1EDP19>
      </E1EDP01>
      <E1EDP01>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>010</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>OBD-2</IDTNR>
         </E1EDP19>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>002</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>000000000010120368</IDTNR>
            <KTEXT>Rocephin Vial 1g</KTEXT>
         </E1EDP19>
         <E1EDP19>
            <QUALF>003</QUALF>
            <IDTNR>07640149612004</IDTNR>
         </E1EDP19>
      </E1EDP01>
   </IDOC>
</INVOIC02>
''')

    def builder = new JsonBuilder()
    builder {
        commonInvoiceInput{
            def qualifier = xml.IDOC.E1EDP01.E1EDP19.collect { codigo -> 
                [codigo.collect { ethnicity -> 
                 codigo.QUALF == '002'}]
            }
                println (qualifier)
                def line = xml.IDOC.E1EDP01
                'itemInfo' line.collect { item -> 
                [
                    'itemCode': item.E1EDP19.IDTNR.text(),
                    'itemName': item.E1EDP19.KTEXT.text(),
                    'lineNumber': item.POSEX.text(),
                    'selection': '',
                    'bathNo': item.E1EDP19.IDTNR.text(),
                    'unitCode': '',
                    'unitName':item.ZE1EDP01.MENEE.text(),
                    'unitPrice': item.E1DP05.KRATE.text(),
                    'quantity': item.MENGE.text(),
                    'itemTotalAmountWithoutTax': '',
                    'TaxPercentage':''
                 ]
                
            }
        }
        }
    println (builder.toPrettyString())
    }
}
```

All "qualifier" that results with true the value from IDTNR goes to 'itemCode' e 'itemName' and when the comparison of 'QUALF' equals '010' value from IDTNR goes to 'batchNo'

Not sure how to make this conditions inside collection properly.

Expected result:

```
{
"commonInvoiceInput": {
    "itemInfo": [
        {
            "itemCode": "000000000010120368",
            "itemName": "Rocephin Vial 1g",
            "lineNumber": "000010",
            "selection": "",
            "bathNo": "",
            "unitCode": "",
            "unitName": "",
            "unitPrice": "",
            "quantity": "0",
            "itemTotalAmountWithoutTax": "",
            "TaxPercentage": ""
        },
        {
            "itemCode": "000000000010120368",
            "itemName": "Rocephin Vial 1g",
            "lineNumber": "",
            "selection": "",
            "bathNo": "OBD-2",
            "unitCode": "",
            "unitName": "",
            "unitPrice": "",
            "quantity": "",
            "itemTotalAmountWithoutTax": "",
            "TaxPercentage": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add to your question the expected result.

Comment: added the expected result.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: the code is in the link

Comment: Please don't link to other sites. Add the code here.

Comment: code added as required.